# How to make jQuery-Plugins available in a JHipster Angular 4 Application

Tags: jquery, angular, jhipster, yarnpkg

In the generated angular application by JHipster, jQuery is available in the whole project by specifying it as a Plugin in the webpack/webpack.common.js file.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            autosize: "autosize",
            Ladda: "ladda",
            Chartist: "chartist"
        }),
```

Now my question: How do I extend jQuery here, that it also loads for example jQuery Ui.

Note: I don't want to have jQuery-ui available as an alias. I want to use it with the '$' or the 'jQuery'